# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre "estar confortable" y "estar a gusto"?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, expresiones

Me parece que las expresiones *estar confortable* y *estar a gusto* suelen ser intercambiables para explicar la sensación de "feeling comfortable" en inglés.

Uno podría decir, por ejemplo:

> Él me parece confortable sentado allí

o

> Él me parece a gusto sentado allí

¿Pero tiene cada expresión algún sentido particular? ¿Hay ocasiones en las que no se debe usar una u otra? ¿O será que son completamente intercambiables?

Comment: Para mí *confortable* es una transliteración del inglés "comfortable". Por eso, siempre uso *cómodo*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Para mi la diferencia radicaría en que `confortable` se usa más para lo físico. Un sofá o una cama son confortables y tú puedes estar a confortable en ellos.

`A gusto` es un poco más abstracto. Viene a significar que te sientes bien en una situación, pero no tiene por qué ser a nivel físico. Por ejemplo, a Juan, que le gusta la magia y el teatro, se siente **a gusto** en el escenario, aunque debido al calor de los focos no siempre **está confortable**.

Uno puede estar **a gusto** en una fiesta, o a solas o en un trabajo. A pesar de que ambas expresiones puedes ser usadas como sinónimos, es menos frecuente oír que alguien está "confortable" en una fiesta (se entendería más en el sentido físico, de estar cómodo, que en el de sentirse feliz en la situación). Si alguien dice que está "a gusto" en el trabajo es que allí le va bien y le gusta lo que hace. Si está "confortable" en el trabajo, se entiende el término como una extensión de lo físico, y viene a significar que está "cómodo, a sus anchas".

Comment: yo siempre usé `confortable` para los objetos: "ese sillón **es** confortable" y para las personas: "ella **está** a gusto" . Aunque si te sientas en una persona... "ella **es** confortable" xDD

Comment: @lois6b pienso igual que tú, de hecho la frase "Él me parece confortable sentado allí" me suena muy rara

Answer (score 6):

En castellano, es mucho más usual "cómodo" que "confortable". También cabe recordar que, salvo que sean indispensables (por ejemplo, para marcar contraste), los pronombres suelen omitirse (de lo contrario, suenan a traducción).

Algo más que observo es que el pronombre "me", si bien es gramaticalmente correcto, produce un efecto de complementación excesiva del verbo copulativo "parece" que no es tan común en la lengua oral o cotidiana, si bien -- reitero -- es perfectamente gramatical. En efecto, por un lado tenemos "me parece a mí" (*It seems to me*) y por otro, "él parece cómodo/a gusto" (*he seems (to be) comfortable/at ease*). La tendencia habitual sería utilizar, al igual que en inglés, una proposición nominal (*It seems to me **that he is comfortable/at ease***), si bien este idioma también nos permite decir: *He seems to me to be comfortable/at ease sitting there.*

Dicho esto, tenemos entonces las oraciones:

1) Me parece que está cómodo sentado allí / Parece cómodo sentado allí.

2) Me parece que está a gusto sentado allí / Parece a gusto sentado allí.

Ambas expresiones, "cómodo" y "a gusto", son muy similares. La única diferencia que observo es que, si se trata sólo de una comodidad "física", tenderemos a utilizar "cómodo". "a gusto" casi exclusivamente se refiere a una comodidad de tipo "emocional", como significando que alguien se siente como en su casa, relajado, en armonía. "cómodo" puede utilizarse en cualquiera de los dos casos (comodidad "física" o "emocional/afectiva").

Comment: Interesante. Nunca entendía el doble uso de la palabra "cómodo". La siempre entendía más de sentido físico. Gracias!

Comment: @Forest Gracias, Forest. Una pequeña corrección a tu comentario. El pronombre siempre va junto al verbo. Lo correcto es: "Siempre la entendía más en un sentido físico."

Answer (score 0):

Sí, hay veces para usar estas oraciones. 
Aunque ambas oraciones son algo similares debemos tener en cuenta qué oración será perfecta por tener el conocimiento apropiado de la situación como `Tensos`, `acciones`, `pensamientos`, etc.

Aquí, `comfortable` and `like` son dos palabras diferentes, pero casi similar en significado, por lo que por la situación de la oración tiene que ser preparado.